Execution failed for task ':react-native-audio:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details
I am trying to run my react-native-app , it gives me this error , how can i solve this
error ?
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file '/home/ahmad/Desktop/New Folder/IOsReactNative-master/node_modules/react-native-audio/android/build.gradle' line: 28

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-audio'.



Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
I replaced method compile() by method implementation() , and after rerun the project it gives me this error :
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-audio:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 12s
error Failed to install the app.
